# .htaccess - try all DirectoryIndex and rewrite if file doesn't exist

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

My `.htaccess` file contains the following directives

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php  
# redirect invalid requests and missing files to the home page  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/ [L]
```

The problem is that many programmers(loosely used term) worked on this site.  Some directories use `index.html` and some use `index.php`.

If a directory uses `index.php`, the request to `www.mydomain.com/directory` looks for `www.mydomain.com/directory/index.html` and is redirected to `www.mydomain.com` before it can look for `www.mydomain.com/directory/index.php`

How can I both try all `DirectoryIndex` files AND redirect missing files to the home page?

Comment: ovverride `.htaccess` in subdirectory with `DirectoryIndex index.php` or `DirectoryIndex index.html`?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I both try all DirectoryIndex files AND redirect missing files
>   to the home page?

I don't think that's possible with mod_rewrite or mod_alias modules. You have to look for other options to solve the problem. Here is an idea using the same DirectoryIndex directive to force the loading of a file at root directory as the last option:

Place this line in one .htaccess file at root directory:

```
DirectoryIndex  index.php  index.html  /missing.php
```

Create `missing.php` in root directory with these lines of code:

```
<?php
header("Location: http://www.example.com/"); // Redirect
?>
```

No additional directives or rules are needed. *missing.php* at root directory will be loaded if none of the previous files (From left to right) is found at the target directory. All requests must have a trailing slash for this to work, though.

*missing,php* is just an example. Any file name can be used.

#### UPDATED with additional option:

> **According to OP comment**: 
>   "But how do I handle missing files such as example.com/file-not-on-server.php"

In this case, `mod_rewrite` is indeed a solution.

You may try this in the .htaccess file at root:

```
# Directive that solves the original question
DirectoryIndex  index.php  index.html  /missing.php

Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# Next condition is met when the requested file doesn't exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# If previous condition was met, use the next rule
RewriteRule ^(.*)$         /index.php [L,NC]
```

NOTES:
1. `/index.php` in the rule, is just an example. It can be any file.
2. For permanent redirection, replace [L,NC] with [R=301,L,NC].

Comment: this is an option that I believe would work BUT I would prefer to handle solely with .htaccess, if possible.  Any thoughts on how to handle WITHOUT a missing.php redirect?

Comment: As I just said in my edited answer, I don't think you can achieve that with mod_rewrite directives. What I suggest is indeed placed in the .htaccess file at root. I understand PHP is much faster than mod_rewrite and in this case more effective. Finally, missing.php is needed to redirect.

Comment: Your solution works fine if the request is for a directory.   But how do I handle missing files such as example.com/file-not-on-server.php